# Why is Route53 registered domain not able resolve EC2 IP while I can access the IP without domain?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

This is what I have right now:

- A domain which is registered with Route53. This domain resides with Route53 only.
- An nginx listening on port 80 which is then running on EC2 instance.
- I can view the webpage served by nginx when I go to this IP on port 80.

Moving forward, I want to setup my domain to point to this IP address. This is what I am doing:

I have a public hosted zone on Route53 for this domain.

- I have created an `A` record in this hosted zone with `Value` set to the IP of the EC2 instance.
- I tried waiting for the TTL time.

I cannot access my nginx hosted webpage when I visit my domain. Am I missing something?

More Info:

- My domain name is santosh.pictures. And IP with nginx is 52.66.136.161.
- I understand rebooting instance will mess up this setup. But that's not the issue I am dealing with right now.
- This is an HTTP only web site at the moment. I want to test this before I proceed with HTTPS setup.
- From chrome, I see a `DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE` error message.
- I noticed that I can't access the server on `ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.aws-region.compute.amazonaws.com`. Could this be related?
- Does this has something to do with my nginx configuraion?

#### Edit 1:

As requested by Tim, here is my whole hosted zone:

[image: hosted zone records]

which are same as listed on **Registered domains** section:

[image]

Comment: Sounds ok so far. Please edit your question to include the domain name and IP address if you'd like help, that way we can inspect public records to see what they say. If you want to do that yourself I use mxtoolbox with a query "a:domainname" then check it against your IP

Comment: mxtoolbox does not responds with IP. Though [Route53 does](https://imgur.com/a/PVbxvKS). Once again, this is a *public* hosted zone. I have updated the question with domain name and public IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your domain has no name servers configured. I've never used Route53 registration, but here's the general kind of steps you'd use

- Register your domain - any registrar
- Create a Route53 public hosted zone including an A record in your case. Route53 will tell you the name servers to use
- Go back to the registrar and input your name servers. It's this step I think you've missed.

[image: MXToolbox]

Comment: When I create the hosted zone, there was a default NS record. I believe that is the nameserver? Correct me if I'm wrong. This is [all the records](https://i.imgur.com/USrbOCP.png) I have at this moment for this domain. For any future answerer reading this comment, these nameservers are the same which are listed on **Registered domains** section in Route53.

Comment: I haven't used R53 registration so I'm not sure. If this doesn't help please edit your question to show screenshots of the domain registration, the name servers configured in the domain registration area, the R53 hosted zone, and the R53 hosted zone screen where it shows the name servers to use for your domain. If you can't find all those you will probably have to get AWS Support for a month to help you.

Comment: Updated the question. The nameservers differ with the one I posted in previous comment. I had to delete the hosted zone. But NS are same on both the places, so should have no problem.

Comment: The DNS is resolving to that IP now, so I think it's all working. I can go to the domain in my web browser, it asks me to log in. If it's all working please mark my answer as correct :)